# type error module object is not callable python gtts

Tags: python, typeerror, gtts

I am using gtts however when i run it it says:

```
TypeError 'module' object is not callable
```

Does anyone know what I should do?
If it helps i am using python 3.8.6 on windows
many thanks
here is the code:

```
import os
from gtts import gTTS
text_to_read = "Hello my name is Alex. What's your name? "
language = 'en'
slow_audio_speed = False
filename = '1.mp3'
def reading_from_string():
    audio_created = gTTS(text=text_to_read, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created.save(filename)
    
    if platform == "linux":
        os.system(f'omxplayer --no-keys {filename}')
    elif platform == 'win32':
        os.system(f'start {filename}')
    else:
        print("I am not compatible with your device")
        exit()

reading_from_string()
```

Comment: Please show us the code you're using

Comment: ok i will show you

Comment: there i edited the question and i added the code

Comment: Your error suggests the problem is calling the module like it is a function. Maybe try doing `import gtts` and calling your function using `gtts.GTTS(text=...)`. Is this the full error message? What line is it? it seems like your code has undefined vars like `platform`. btw I don't get this error.

Comment: Will try this tysm